# Make TextView as big as parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a LinearLayout XML as shown below and I want the last TextView in the layout to match the entire width of the linear layout. I have added a drawable as a background to the TextView. Here's the XML file (I have omitted unnecessary code) -

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/received_interaction_row_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_red"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_contact"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp" ..... />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_event" ..... />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_feedback"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp" ...... />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_pink"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is how it looks currently - 
[image: Current Layout]

I want the remove the padding of the last TextView (the one with dark background) and make it appear as wide as the parent layout. I also want to remove the bottom padding.

The drawable background has some padding in it but I tried removing that as well, and that didn't work.

EDIT 1 - Given below is what I want to achieve. Notice the darker blue background at the bottom.

[image: Layout needed]

Comment: Do you have any expected design image for this?

Comment: "rounded_corner_red" is this XML drawable or image?

Comment: There would be padding inside rounded_corner_red.xml. remove it.

Comment: no, I mean wireframe

Comment: yeah. reason is either margin for the text view or padding for the parent layout.

Comment: Use `Framelayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and  another approach is use drawable in `Linearlayout` or `RelativeLayout` inside you main layout.

Comment: what is your problem give image for what you accept.

Comment: Please share rounded_bottom_pink and  rounded_corner_red

Comment: Please provide full detail *XML* as it's looks missing so many properties out their in *Text Views*. Please post entire *XML* with relevant to *drawable xml* files.

Comment: Use relative layout instead of linear. also avoid using of margin.

Comment: You need to create two inner linear layout inside your parent linear layout. Don't give padding or margin to parent layout.In the first child linear layout give margin or padding as per your desire and in the second child linear layout don't give any padding or margin so it will fill the entire parent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most vector drawable might contain padding of its own.
You might need to change your rounded_corner_red.xml. check below vector file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ff0090" />
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
<padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

You need to use vector files without padding, please refer below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ff0090" />
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: My drawable does not include any padding.

Comment: Oops. then I will get you with another solution.

Comment: Your solution works. The parent layout's background drawable had padding in it. The TextView drawable was fine.

Comment: Yeah, rounded_corner_red.xml.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: To mark my own answer as "accepted", I need to wait for 2 days. I think that's because my reputation is really low on StackOverflow

Comment: So you are saying that my answer didn't fix your issue? And your answer itself is right?

Answer (score 0):

> Remove margin from parent LinearLayout. Add these margin to TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/received_interaction_row_layout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_red"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:elevation="3dp"
>
<TextView
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_contact"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp" ..... />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_event" ..... />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_feedback"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp" ...... />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_pink"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that as well. Removing margins from the parent gave me the same result as above.

Comment: Do you have padding or margin in LinearLayout foreground and background shape? Also check for drawablePadding inside TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. Turns out the padding was present in the background of the parent LinearLayout which was causing this problem. The drawable background for the TextView contained no padding but the LinearLayout's background did, which was causing the above problem. I removed padding from the "rounded_corner_red" drawable which is the background of the parent layout.